# Move GIT including their branchs and tags from A to B

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have a project that use 2 different git. Both of them are the same app and what different it is a version & language. Consider `Folder_1` directory is `Version_1` project and `Folder_2` directory is `Version_2` project.

**Explanation:**

- In `Folder_1`, I use C language.
- And in `Folder_2` I use C# language

**Directory:**

```
|-- Local Disk (D:)
    |-- Folder_1 (D:\Folder_1)
    |-- Folder_2 (D:\Folder_2)
```

**Folder_1 git structure:**

```
Init --- Branch1 --- Dev
   \--- Branch2 --- Master
```

**Folder_2 git structure:**

```
Init --- Dev
   \--- BranchX --- Master
    \--- Test
```

### QUESTION:

1. How do I combine or copy or move `Folder_1` git structure into `Folder_2` git?

**Desired output:**

```
Init --- Dev
  \--- BranchX --- Master
   \-- Test
    \- v1_Init
            \--- v1_Branch1 --- v1_Dev
             \-- v1_Branch2 --- Version_1
```

2. It is a bad practice of doing that? & If the answer is yes, could explain why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make one Git repo that has branches with unrelated histories all you have to do is "fetch" the objects and create the "refs".

```
cd repo2
git remote add repo1 /path/to/repo1
git fetch repo1
git branch v1_Dev repo1/Dev
git branch v1_Master repo1/Master
```

Now you can switch between the two projects just by switching branch:

```
git checkout v1_Master
git checkout master
```